# Using Random Forests as a GAM

Tags: python, regression, random-forest

This is a regression problem. I have a dataset of sales of various products overtime.  I have three kind of feature sets : `Price features`, `Product features` and `Seasonality`.

I want to build a customer estimator which is defined as follows : `y = a*price_features + RandomForest(Product features + Seasonality features)`.

Moreover if there would be a possibility to switch `RandomForest` with some other non linear estimator it would be even better.

So the model is linear for price features and non linear for product and seasonality features. How can i do something like this in python ? I am interpreting this problem as `GAMs` because I express the model as a sum of Linear and Nonlinear components. I know that `GAMs` are fitted using `backfitting` but i dont know if I should take the pain of writing the whole backfitting algorithm. Also i am pretty sure there isnt a package which provides the functionality to use `RandomForest`as a `GAM`. I would really appreciate some insights. Thanks